# groupby results of a matching function

Tags: group-by, jq

given the below sample json, what i need to do, is to find if each value found in serialno, exists in serialnopool. If this holds TRUE, then i need a way, to have the values of serialno, that were found in serialnopool, grouped, along with their corresponding row ids.

example output of serialno value **11079851** that exists in serialnopool:

**11079851: 098, 798**, etc, each serialno value would go on with its new line.
Follows the sample json:

```
 [
      {
        "rowid": "098",
        "serialno": 11079851,
        "serialnopool": 11079851
      },
      {
        "rowid": 110,
        "serialno": 11089385,
        "serialnopool": 25853201
      },
      {
        "rowid": 118,
        "serialno": 11089385,
        "serialnopool": 22412115
      },
      {
        "rowid": 798,
        "serialno": 11079851,
        "serialnopool": 22412115
      },
      {
        "rowid": "",
        "serialno": "",
        "serialnopool": 5423
      },
      {
        "rowid": "",
        "serialno": "",
        "serialnopool": 5421312
      }
    ]
```

How could this be achieved with the use of jq?

Comment: i need to check if each value found in serialno, exists in serialnopool. Then group all equal - same serialno values that existed in serialnopool, along with their corresponding row ids, like in the example output

Comment: Not clear at all. What do you mean by **existing in serialnopool**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that by "exists in serialnopool" you mean "occurs at least once in the set of serialnopool values", the following is a solution provided that your jq is version 1.5 or higher:

```
map(.serialnopool) as $snp
| (INDEX( group_by(.serialno)[]; .[0].serialno|tostring)
   | map_values(map(.rowid))) as $dict
| (map(.serialno) | unique[]) as $sn
| if IN($sn; $snp[])
  then "\($sn): " + ($dict[$sn|tostring] | join(", "))
  else empty end
```

The main point of interest in this solution is the dictionary ($dict), which maps `.serialno|tostring` values to the corresponding `.rowid` values.